# fsockopen() error 500 when I try to access my Symfony app after deployment to Ubuntu VPS

Tags: php, symfony, web-deployment, vps, ubuntu-server

EDIT2: APC is installed and enabled. what would be the solution?

I'm trying to deploy a symfony app to a VPS.
I deployed the code from git ok, I installed vendors and check /web/config.php to fix all the major and recommended issues on Symfony requirements. It's all green.

However, when I try to access the [VPS_IP]/my_project/web/app.php I get a **page isn't working. [my_ip] is currently unable to handle the request.**

I also tried to configure virtual host and try to access my Symfony app on the [my_ip] only as URL address and I get the same result.

I've enabled apache 2 mod rewrite, I've added and enabled all the necessary php extensions, I've set date.timezone in php.ini, I've also looked in the dev.log files and tehre I have this error which may be the cause:

```
[2016-11-22 14:45:49] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:800           0 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony           /symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59           ,"level":28928} []
```

Could anyone provide some help?

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@MyVendorBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

# app/config/config.yml
#knp_menu:
    # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
#    twig:
#        template: knp_menu.html.twig
    #  if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
#    templating: false
    # the renderer to use, list is also available by default
#    default_renderer: twig

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

gregwar_captcha: ~

liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        cover_filter:
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size: [600, 400]
                    mode: inset
        prod_thumbnail:
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size: [50, 50]
                    mode: inset

#web_profiler:
#    toolbar: true
#    position: bottom
#    intercept_redirects: false
#    excluded_ajax_paths:  ^/bundles|^/_wdt
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: [another remote DB IP]
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: [remote DB name]
    database_user: [Remote DB user]
    database_password: [remote DB PSW]
    mailer_transport: sendmail
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: rodacsoft
    facebook_app_id: [fb_app_ID] 
    facebook_app_secret: [fb_secret]
```

VPS /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/giftbundle/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/giftbundle/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: in the Symfony_error.log I have this. No clue how to fix it or if it's related.

```
[Tue Nov 22 14:46:06.216187 2016] [:error] [pid 21788] [client 159.153.60.77:18035] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "validator.builder" has a dependency on a non-existent service "validator.mapping.cache.apc". in /var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:58\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(51): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(51): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnIn in /var/www/html/giftbundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 58
```

Comment: From the error log, I think that your Symfony project has APC cache enabled, and your server does not have apc cache installed

Comment: @Szanto apcache is enabled from what I see in phpinfo. How would I go about fixing this though? Changing Symfony app cache that it uses to be with something else in case my server is on something else than what I think?

Comment: @SzántóZoltán Or better yet, how do I configure Symfony to use server Memcache?

Comment: Sincerely, I'm not familiar with Symfony, but you can try disabling the mapping cache completely by setting the cache value to false in your yml files.

Comment: I don't have any APC entry in config.yml

Comment: @SzántóZoltán - I trid to install APCu on my VPS and I got the message that it is already present. SO I do have it... any other ideas? do I need to something extra to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if cache folder is writable by apache (www-data) user. You cannot access [VPS_IP]/my_project/web/app.php because you already defined web/ folder as root folder in apache config. You should define ServerName and ServerAlias in apache config with your domain name or try direct access to [VPS_IP]/app.php.
Also enter your IP to app_dev and access [VPS_IP]/app_dev.php for more clear errors.

Comment: Cache folder is writable, I solved permissions. I also tried with IP and not web folder, as I had configured my virtual host. Same problem. I'll try to get app_dev.php to check, but for that give me info if vendors are installed with --no-dev?

Comment: I added app_dev.php and when I access that the page loads, but without formatting and assets, even though they are present in the web folder. 
So, why doesn't it work without app_dev?

Comment: I fixed the document root path and the assets load fine on app_dev.php, but when I try to access regularly for prod I get that **page isn't working. [my_ip] is currently unable to handle the request.**